# Arithmetic operations between 2 hash arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hashmap, perl-data-structures

I have a hash array with a YAML, which was taken from a linux command. I have another hash array, with the same YAML set, but with different values, by the same command, which was run at a later time.

Eg.

```
content.none: 
  bytes:  31046
content.image.gif: 
  bytes:  0
```

and

```
content.none: 
  bytes:  31050
content.image.gif: 
  bytes:  0
```

Now, I am looking for a math operation between the values. I am looking for an output

```
content.none: 
  bytes:  4
content.image.gif: 
  bytes:  0
```

which is the result of math between the corresponding values in the hash.

I tried iterating and doing diff, but it looks like a cumulative output.

```
%host_stat_new=New stats
 %host_stat_old=Old stats (taken from stats.yml, which contains old data)
while (true){
open my $FH1, ">stats.yml" or die "cannot write to stat file because $!\n";
foreach my $line4 (keys %host_stat_new){
        print $FH1 "$line4:\n";
        foreach my $line5 (keys %{$host_stat_new{$line4}}) {
                print $FH1 "  $line5: \n";
                foreach my $line6 (keys %{$host_stat_new{$line4}{$line5}}){
                my $diff1 = $host_stat_new{$line4}{$line5}{$line6};
                my $diff2 = $host_stat_old{$line4}{$line5}{$line6};


$math=$diff1-$diff2;
#$host_stat1{$line4}{$line5}{$line6} = $math;
$host_stat_new{$line4}{$line5}{$line6} = $math;
                    print $FH1 "    $line6:  $host_stat_new{$line4}{$line5}{$line6}\n";
                    }
            }


    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any module that can do this?

Comment: And what happens? What output is expected, what output is given? Could you use Data::Dumper on `%host_stat_old` and `new` so we can see how that hash is filled? Do you `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: The output, at the first time, goes as a diff, but from the second iteration, it comes up as cumulative. Yes, Strict and Warnings are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use some good ole recursion to get the diff.  This function assumes that the data structures are identical, could add functionality to confirm that:

```
use YAML;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str1 = <<YAML_STRING1;
content.none: 
  bytes:  31046
content.image.gif: 
  bytes:  0
YAML_STRING1

my $str2 = <<YAML_STRING2;
content.none: 
  bytes:  31050
content.image.gif: 
  bytes:  0
YAML_STRING2

my $data1 = Load($str1);
my $data2 = Load($str2);

my $diff = diff_recurse($data2, $data1);

print Dump($diff);

sub diff_recurse {
    my ($str1, $str2) = @_;

    my $diff;

    if ('HASH' eq ref $str1) {
        $diff = {};
        for my $key (keys %$str1) {
            $diff->{$key} = diff_recurse($str1->{$key}, $str2->{$key});
        }

    } elsif ('ARRAY' eq ref $str1) {
        $diff = [];
        for my $i (0..$#$str1) {
            $diff->[$i] = diff_recurse($str1->[$i], $str2->[$i]);
        }

    } elsif (my $unknown = ref $str1) {
        die "Unknown type $unknown\n";

    } elsif ($str1 =~ /^[\d\.]+$/) {
        $diff = $str1 - $str2;
    } else {
        $diff = $str1;
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Outputs

```
---
content.image.gif:
  bytes: 0
content.none:
  bytes: 4
```